# Can sending a hidden Text/SMS messages be considered a security issue?

Tags: mobile, bluetooth

**tl;dr:** *My Toyota Aygo sends Text/SMS messages through Bluetooth and my mobile phone. These messages are delivered to the recipient, but there is no sign of them in my Messages app.*

*Should I be concern? Is this some kind of security issue?*

---

My car (Toyota Aygo 2019+), when connected with my phone (Motorola Moto Z2 Play) through paired Bluetooth connection, is able to send "hidden" Text/SMS messages. That is:

- message is written and sent by me through car's navigation panel,
- the fact that message was sent is confirmed on panel's screen and
- message is delivered to the recipient, *but*
- **there's no sign of that message on my phone**.

It is like that -- when browsing through history of the messages sent by me to a particular recipient, I can see messages sent from by me, from my phone only, i.e.:

- all the messages sent before any message sent by Toyota and
- all the messages sent after any message sent by Toyota, but
- no message ever sent using Toyota's panel, through Bluetooth.

At first, I thought that this is a bug in Toyota and car isn't actually send anything (despite confirmation message). But then I have realised that messages are actually sent and delivered.

I understand that this could be caused by a variety of factors:

- bug in Toyota's implementation of Bluetooth protocol*,
- bug in Messages application on my Motorola,
- some technical issues at my mobile carrier side,
- bug in Android 7 (?),
- bug in Bluetooth protocol (???) etc.

**But, still... shouldn't I be concerned that (at a high level) *something* is able to send Text/SMS messages through Bluetooth and my phone without me knowing anything about that fact?**

I have, of course, contacted Toyota support, but I have got only a template-like answer that their implementation of Bluetooth is as close to standard as possible, but even so they cannot assure that any Bluetooth-enabled phone is compatible with their cars.

I have contacted my mobile carrier, but I have got even worse answer in "never heard of" style.

<sup>*Unfortunately, I do not have any other Bluetooth device, capable of sending Text/SMS messages, to verify whether this is caused by Bluetooth protocol or Toyota's implementation of it.</sup>

Comment: I suspect your mistake comes from conflating "Sending a text message" and your "Messages" app.  Food for thought: if you send a message through whatsapp it also won't show up in your message history.  This is likely just a small variation on that.  Certainly bluetooth has nothing to do with this.  Bluetooth is just a way for your car and phone to communicate.  There is no such thing as a "Bluetooth device capable of sending text/sms messages".  The bluetooth protocol does not send text messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens is that your phone "exports" a **modem**. This is visible via Bluetooth and can be programmed using AT commands (in this case, `AT+CMGW`).

And *those* can be used by the SMS App to send SMSs, and also by the Toyota to do the same.

This can be done by **any** device that is paired (trusted) and has access to the Bluetooth stack.

Since SMSs are not stored by the *modem* but by the *app*, you won't see any messages from any app from any other app (unless the two apps "agree" to a protocol and store messages where they both can access them).

Checking what was done by such applications [is probably possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39270079/how-to-capture-modem-radio-log-in-android) but would require a specific utility to do so.

To verify that no unknown stranger is abusing your radio modem console, you need to *not pair with any untrusted device, ever*, and periodically verify what devices your phone has paired with.